# Run multiple sql scripts in perl

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have 5 .sql scripts that create tables and insert into the tables. . I want to run them together as a transaction in PERL.
I have searched for it in Google and SO , but only I could find about running the scripts using Batch script. 
I have no idea how to run the scripts together using PERL DBI as a transaction . 
Can anyone please help. 
I am new to perl and mysql and I have no idea how to do that .

This is what I am trying to do based on the suggestions by Barmar:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $user="root";
my $password="M3m01r!@#";
my $db="DBI:$driver:database=$database";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=testdb;mysql_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock",$user,$password) or die "could not connect $DBI::errstr\n";
my $st = $dbh->prepare("mysql -u root -p < rr.sql") or die "$DBI::errstr\n";
$st->execute();
```

But it throws  this error

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p < rr.sql' at line 1 at dbi.pl line 15.
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Just read the files into Perl variables, and then execute them using Perl DBI.

Comment: How can I rollback if a file fails?

Comment: Or is there a way , where I can have all the 5 sql scripts in one sql script and execute that single sql script that runs all the other sql script

Comment: Forget about scripts. They're just SQL queries. Once you put them in Perl variables, it doesn't matter where they came from. You use Perl DBI the same as if you'd put the queries in Perl directly.

Comment: You cannot "share" a transaction over multiple batched files. Put them together and execute it with DBI as @Barmar said.

Comment: You can set the autocommit to false and run them in through the same $dbh, splitting them first then call `$dbh->commit()` or `$dbh->rollback()`  http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ############################################################################
 my $st = $dbh->prepare("mysql -u root -p < rr.sql") or die "$DBI::errstr\n";
 ############################################################################
```

Line 2 is where you're broken.

The string that you feed to prepare is supposed to be the actual SQL. You've fed it a shell command intended to run mysql.  So take the contents of rr.sql, put it in a variable (either have your program read it in, or copy/paste it), and then call prepare() on the variable.

```
 my $ferret_query = "select name, dob, type from ferret order by dob";
 my $sth = $dbh->prepare($ferret_query);
 $sth->execute()
```